# Scraping multiple tables along with their headers on a Wikipedia page using python requests and BeatifulSoup?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Using python libraries, request and BeautifulSoup, I am trying to scrape the tables on this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code. I can get all the data in the tables; however, I want to add another column called Country, from table names, populate it with table names.[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHjsy.png) is an example,
Wikipedia table(above) and the desired table(below).

The code below allows me to get all the data without the Country column:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

wiki = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code')
soup = BeautifulSoup(wiki.content, 'html.parser')

# Get all the tables
tables = soup.find_all('table',class_="wikitable")

# extract the column names
column_names = [item.get_text() for item in tables[0].find_all('th')]

# extract the content
contents = [item.get_text() for item in tables[0].find_all('td')]

# put all the content into a list
values=[]
for table in tables:
    for item in table.select('td'):
        temp = item.get_text()
        values.append(temp)

# Since there are 7 columns, obtain the number of rows and reshape the table
len(values)/7   # 2452 rows

# change the shape of the table
data = np.reshape(values,(2452,7))

# put all the data into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns=header_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
#This is the table which I want to extract
# Get all the tables
tables = soup.find_all('table',class_="wikitable")

# extract the column names
column_names = [item.get_text() for item in tables[0].find_all('th')]

# extract the content
contents = [item.get_text() for item in tables[0].find_all('td')]

# put all the content into a list

values_list = []
#find all countries
countries = soup.find_all('h3')
international = [soup.find('span',{"id":"International_operators"}).parent]
countries = countries+international
for c in countries:
    table = c.find_next_sibling("table")
    if table is not None: #check the coutries has table
        for item in table.select('tr')[1:]:
            values = [e.get_text() for e in item.select('td')]
            values = [c.text]+values
            values_list.append(values)

header_list = ["COUNTRY"]+ column_names

# put all the data into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(values_list, columns=header_list)
```

`df` will be:

```
    COUNTRY             MCC MNC Brand    Operator       Status       Bands (MHz)                                        References and notes
0   Abkhazia - GE-AB    289 67  Aquafon  Aquafon JSC    Operational GSM 900 / GSM 1800 / UMTS 2100 / LTE 800            MCC is not listed by ITU;[85] LTE band 20[95]
1   Abkhazia - GE-AB    289 88  A-Mobile A-Mobile LLSC  Operational GSM 900 / GSM 1800 / UMTS 2100 / LTE 800 / LTE...   MCC is not listed by ITU[85]
...
```

Comment: Thanks Tiny.D, I appreciate the quick reply. One question: because there is no recored for "Ascension Island - AC" the country names have been shifted. For instance, all records from "Australia" are now belongs to "Ascension Island". How can it be fixed?

Comment: @steve check the updated answer, it will work for the countries which has tables.